# error: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "172.27.0.5", what?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, rabbitmq, nestjs

I have an error that has been haunting me for days, when I try to compile my auth(rabbitmq) and my hyper(api gateway) my api kinda works, I need to download some packages, but my auth gives a Postgres error.

My pg_hba.conf

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     md5
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     md5
host    replication     all             all                     md5
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 md5
```

when I try to compile, I get this error:

Error?:

```
 ERROR [TypeOrmModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (4)...
error: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "172.27.0.5", user "hypex", database "Hyper", no encryption
```

obs: I cant enter my database, its the same error again

Its internal error? I doing something bad?, any solution?

Comment: Have you looked up any documentation on pg_hba.conf? At a glance, the error seems to be correct: there is no line in the file matching that IP address. Perhaps you can be more specific about where you are stuck?

Comment: yeah, Should I change something or add something? I don't want to change something and have it all go wrong.

Comment: So, I can access the Postgres portal, but when I try to connect to my database, it says: Fatal: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "172.27.0.5", user "hypex", database "Hyper", no encryption, my password and user is right

Comment: As I say, have you looked up any documentation about what the file is for and how it works? The best way to avoid "having it all go wrong" is to understand what the file means, and what change you're making; if somebody gives you the answer, you should *still* be doing that, as they could be giving you bad or even malicious advice (I hope not, but you shouldn't _assume_).

Comment: Once you've _tried_ to understand the file, and maybe tried an edit to the file that didn't work, you can come back with a more specific question about why that didn't solve the problem. But at the moment, your question could essentially be rephrased as "what is pg_hba.conf and how do I edit it?" and that's too broad a question for this site's format.

Comment: From what I researched, it should work, because I didn't do or change or implement anything wrong, that's why I lost help here, I was thinking about adding this IP that it shows in the error instead of ''all''' but it didn't. I'm sure, I'll look into this document like you said.

Comment: It's not about "doing something wrong", it's about "changing the configuration to suit your particular use case". Not everybody connects to their database in the same way, and from the same address, so there's no way that the default configuration can perfectly match your requirements.

Comment: `no encryption`, your server requires md5. However, scram-sha-256 is better. After every change in pg_hba.conf you have to reload the config in your database server. Or restart the server

Comment: @FrankHeikens Even with an md5 connection, none of the lines shown match, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: I understand perfectly, I'll try to solve it and add what I need to connect

Comment: well, without success, but I'll try again tomorrow, but thanks for the answers, I'm able to understand how these files work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed it, after thousands of trials and errors, I uninstalled postgres sql because it had already been installed for a long time, then I installed it again and configured it in another way without md5, with scram-sha-256 which was recommended by @Frank Heikens, and after I created another project, I just copied the same information and changed my .env codes, when I compiled again both auth(rabbitmq) and my gateway api worked, I understood how pg_hba.conf works, I think. Thank you to those who helped me.

my pg_hba.conf after:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all             all                        scram-sha-256
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             all            scram-sha-256
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 scram-sha-256
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   all     all             all                        scram-sha-256
host    all     all             all            scram-sha-256
host    all     all             ::1/128                 scram-sha-256
```